# Available documentations about the “alerttemplates.xml” fields name and layout classes

Tags: 2013, development, css, alert, xml

I want to modify the default alerttemplates .xml alert template. But seems the only way to hide, display and change the components format is to know exactly the name of each components . Such as the name of the link labelled “Mobile View” etc.

Currently the default alert for my announcement list looks as follow:-

[image]

So if  I want to remove certain links such s “Mobile View” or change the background colour for my table , I should know the item name and class name. so my question is basically if there is any available documentation which describes these fields and classes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is standard MSDN documentation:

1. [Predefined Alert Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802738.aspx)
2. [AlertTemplates schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802961(v=office.15).aspx)